# iOS UIAccessibility.post - do I have to check if VoiceOver is running?

Tags: ios, swift, voiceover, uiaccessibility

I'm just looking at the documentation https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiaccessibility/1615194-post

It doesn't mention if there's any side effect if the method is called without VoiceOver being turned on, so is it right to think that it's just posting the notification with no one listens to it? Other than this, is there any side effect?

Thanks!

Comment: You dont have to check if VO is running or not before posting a notification. It is unnecessary unless some part of your code listen to that notification and do something it's supposed to do when VO is running , in that case you can do the extra check

Answer (score 0):

Yes you should post the notification and operating system should decide what is the best after that. Technically accessibility post may in the future work with some other systems so you shouldn't consider it as the VoiceOver only feature.